# Infinite $\sigma$-algebras are uncountable proof error

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, set-theory, solution-verification

I was posed this problem this morning, and I thought I had come up with a nice solution. I went to the internet to see if anyone proved it the same way I did, and found that there appears to be one standard proof that, while not hard to follow, is more involved than what I thought of. Usually when I'm in this situation I soon realize I have made an error, but I cannot find what's wrong with my idea. It goes as follows:

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be an infinite $\sigma$-algebra on the (infinite) set $X$. Suppose $\mathcal{M}$ is countable. Then we can list the elements of $\mathcal{M}$ as $A_1,A_2,...$. Let $A=\bigcup_{A_n\subset X} A_n$. That is, $A$ is the union of all sets in $\mathcal{M}$ that are proper subsets of $X$. Since this is a countable union, $A\in \mathcal{M}$. Therefore for some $j\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $A=A_j$, and $A_N=A_j$ for all $N\geq j$. In which case $\mathcal{M}$ is finite, contradicting our hypothesis. Thus, if $\mathcal{M}$ is infinite it must be uncountable infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you consider only the members of $\mathcal{M}$ which are proper subsets of $X$, the union will be $X$.

Since $\mathcal{M}$ is infinite, there exists $A\in\mathcal{M}$ such that $A\ne\emptyset$ and $A\ne X$. But then $X\setminus A\in\mathcal{M}$ and therefore the union you're considering is $X$.

Answer (score 1):

For one, $X$ is one of the sets $A_j$ so the union is $X$. But that does *not* mean that the tail of the sequence is all $X$, they don't hva eany effect on the union as soon as $X$ is in it..

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any reason why we would get $A_N = A_j$ for all $N \geq j$.  The listing $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ was essentially arbitrary.

You might try to fix this by asking that if $i < j$ then $A_i \subset A_j$, but there's no reason why such an arrangement should be possible (in general $\subset$ is not a linear order on subsets of $X$).